# Trying to locate hrefs deep in a websites html with VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba, element, href

I am trying to locate all website hyperlink on a specific webpage including the text used for the hyperlink using VBA.

The website is https://cdl.demosphere.com/ and I am trying to locate div.tg which is deep in the URL, see picture below. For example I am trying to grab https://elements.demosphere-secure.com/scripts/runisa.dll?M2.65878:gp:229365.6993:74908+Elements/Display+E+46241++111127392 from the element listed below including the text "U13-U14 Girls" directly after the link

[Picture of the href I am trying to get to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qqy1g.png)

I am trying to to not use ie. See the code below that I have already tried

```
Sub test()

    Const Url = "https://cdl.demosphere.com/"
    Dim Html As HTMLDocument, I&
    
    Set Html = New HTMLDocument

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", Url, False
        .send
        Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    
    With Html.getElementsByTagName(".tg")
        For I = 0 To .Length - 1
            Cells(I, 1) = .Item(I).href
        Next I
    End With


End Sub
```

I have also tried replacing  With Html.getElementsByTagName("div") which got me results but the "div" was not deep enough in the html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all links you don't need any div tags. You can get directly the a tags.

```
Sub ExampleToGetURLs()

    Const url As String = "http://elements.demosphere.com/74908/schedules/Fall2023/111127392.html?1704485956"
    Dim doc As Object
    Dim nodesAllA As Object
    Dim nodeOneA As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim currRow As Long
    
    Set doc = CreateObject("htmlFile")
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    currRow = 1
    
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
        .Open "GET", url, False
        .send
        
        If .Status = 200 Then
            doc.body.innerHTML = .responseText
            Set nodesAllA = doc.getElementsByTagName("a")
            For Each nodeOneA In nodesAllA
                ws.Cells(currRow, 1) = nodeOneA.href
                ws.Cells(currRow, 2) = nodeOneA.innerText
                currRow = currRow + 1
            Next nodeOneA
        Else
            MsgBox "Page not loaded. HTTP status " & .Status
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Zwenn, this did help with a down the stream process for what I am trying to accomplish as your solution works when we locate that html. I tried reproducing this from the original website and located the html. Do you have any suggestions to accomplish the same thing using: https://elements.demosphere-secure.com/scripts/runisa.dll?M2.262450:gpx::74908+Elements/Display+E+46241+Short/++++111127389#is_embedded=true thanks again for the help!

Comment: It looks as if the contents of the page are generated or reloaded via JavaScript. Such dynamic processes cannot be carried out with xhr (XML HTTP Request), as xhr only retrieves a static document from the web server, which is then available exactly as delivered. Browser automation is required to scrape dynamic pages. This would probably work with SeleniumBasic.